# How to fetch webpage console object in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have a scenario where I need to validate a PDFTron object which has the entire pdf content in it. I cannot do that with selenium since it's a canvas in DOM.
I am able to log the object using Javascript executer as:
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) this.WebDriver;
js.ExecuteScript("console.log(PDFTron)");

After this, the console looks like this
[enter image description here][1]

And I need to get this web viewer object in c# to proceed with validation. Any help/suggestion is appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkdXg.png

Comment: Did you found any answer to it?